# How to call void function with array and reference arguments

Tags: c++

Good evening, I'm attempting to call my void function "getProblems" in main, but get an extraneous value when outputting "getProblems" with no parameters. Similarly, when passing arguments, such as "getProblems(list, i)", I get the error "no operator '<<' matches these operands". The goal is to output the number of problems my text file contains without using a function that returns a value or using pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
int const MAX_PROBLEMS = 50;
void getProblems(string  problem[], int& count);

int main()
{
string list[MAX_PROBLEMS] = {};
int i = 0;
    cout << "There are " << getProblems << " problems. " << endl;
//  I have also tried calling the void function with parameters
//  cout << "There are " << getProblems(list, i) << "problems. " << endl;

    return 0;
}
void getProblems(string  problem[], int& count)
{

    ifstream mathProblems;
        mathProblems.open("P4Problems.txt");
        if (!mathProblems)
            {
                cout <<"No file was found."<< endl;
            }
        count = 0;
        string data;

        getline(mathProblems, data);
            while (!mathProblems.eof())
                {
                    problem[count] = data;
                    count ++;
                    mathProblems >> data;
                }
        mathProblems.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello songyuanyao, I have tried passing a string array "list" and int "i", but get the error message described on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getProblems()` is of type `void`, so what are you trying to display with `cout`?

If you need to display the count, which is an argument,

```
int main()
{
    int count;
    getProblems(listt,count); //assuming listt, has been declared before
    cout << "There are " << count << " problems. " << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```